# Does single static method can cause the test failure in parallel execution - selenium

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing

I'm using Selenium to automate the testcases. I'm executing the testcase in parallel mode using TestNG where it causing some random test failure. If I execute the same in non parallel mode then all test getting pass.

I come to know the thing from [here](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Things+That+Can+Go+Wrong+with+Running+Java+Tests+in+Parallel%2C+and+How+to+Debug+Them) that static resource in you code can cause the issue.

I've one common class where i have created some common method and all method are static. e.g.

```
public static String formatString(String loc, String val) {

        return String.format(getBundle().getString(loc), getBundle().getString(val));
    }

    public static QAFWebElement getQAFExtendedWebElement(String loc, String str) {

        return new QAFExtendedWebElement(
                String.format(getBundle().getString(loc), getBundle().getString(str)));
    }

    public static void assertResult(String actual, String expected) {

        assertTrue(actual.contains(expected),
                "FAILED : Actual : " + actual + " Expected : " + expected,
                "PASSED : Actual : " + actual + " Expected : " + expected);
    }
```

So my question is do I need to make all these method non static or it doesn't have any impact with parallel execution ?

Answer (score 2):

This can definetly cause random failures. There will only be one instance of a static resource in your process. This means that every thread which is trying to access this static resources can come in a situation where another thread is trying to access the same static resources.

Let us take an example of your ::assertResult function. This function can be accessed by two threads at the same time with different values of 'actual' and 'expected' parameters. As the assertTrue is not an atomic operation the data (actual and expected) values can be intermingled between the two threads. This can cause unexpected results for you. I would recommend a better multithreading capable design for you but to quickly fix this issue you can use synchronized keyword in function definition of all the methods that can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time.

```
public synchronized static void assertResult(String actual, String expected) {

    assertTrue(actual.contains(expected),
            "FAILED : Actual : " + actual + " Expected : " + expected,
            "PASSED : Actual : " + actual + " Expected : " + expected);
}
```

Although there are better solutions than adding synchronized keyword, which should come up in your redesign exercise. One visible problem of adding synchronized keyword will be an increase in execution time by a minor factor in this case. This is because multiple threads will start waiting for other threads when they try to access the synchronized method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. let me try and come to the conclusion